# Beyond CVS Eclipse Plug-In Problem

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, beyondcompare3

I have installed the Beyond CVS Eclipse Plug-In version 0.8.9
I use eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios), windows 7 64 bit, beyond compare 3, subclipse.

I configured the external Diff/Merge tool:

[image]

But when I compare:

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

The path specified for beyond compare in the first screenshot exists, there are no problems there. But for somewhat reason, the error says otherwise. I can't figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI you show for setting the external diff/merge is a Subclipse feature.  It only applies to launching an external tool for resolving conflicts after update or merge.  The BeyondCompare plugin perhaps has some UI in Eclipse to tell it where the executable is located.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this indeed was the problem. I am editing your post to add a screenshot, where to configure the location of beyond compare :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log; maybe an exception was logged which tells you more.